# Why does Microsft Project leave empty days after leveling?

Tags: microsoft-project

I have a resource with a recurring task for support duty. The task recurs every Tuesday and Wednesday until Dec 2010.

When I create a new task for the resource, even a 1 day task and level, the task is pushed till after the last occurrence or the recurring task. (I allow splitting)

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it happens but I can reproduce the problem.

When I've been forced to use MS Project for this level of micro-management, I usually model the support tasks with resource availability. So if a resource is only available on 3 days of a working week, I make the resource a 60% resource, with a comment telling that 40% of the work time is spent on support tasks.